# Rails alternate actions for index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im working on a filter system and running into a conflict with how I load my search results.  Im using a jquery-infinite-scroll plugin to load more results as the user scrolls.  As such I have an index.js.erb that appends the extra results:

```
$("#recipes").append("<%= escape_javascript(render 'recipe_card') %>");
<% if @recipes.last_page? %>
  $('#paginator').html("No More Recipes");
<% else %>
  $('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(link_to_next_page(@recipes, "Next Page", remote: true).to_s) %>');
<% end %>
```

The problem arises when I try to implement my filter.  Im using a form with checkboxes that are used as a search criteria.  Here is the form_tag:

```
<%= form_tag(recipes_path, :method => "get", id: "Filters", remote: true, html: {class: "form-horizontal"}) do %>
```

The problem is this uses the same index route as the kaminari pages that get loaded with the scrolling.  So it appends the filtered results instead of replacing them.  Im having trouble figuring out how to add a route to use a different controller action.  I have added this to my controller:

```
def filter
    @recipes = RecipeSearch.new(query: params[:search], options: params).search
  end
```

And then created a filter.js.erb file:

```
$("#recipes").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'recipe_card') %>");
<% if @recipes.last_page? %>
  $('#paginator').html("No More Recipes");
<% else %>
  $('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(link_to_next_page(@recipes, "Next Page", remote: true).to_s) %>');
<% end %>
```

Just cant figure out how to change the form_tag to route to that action...I tried this:

```
<%= form_tag(recipes_path, url: {action: 'filter'}, :method => "get", id: "Filters", remote: true, html: {class: "form-horizontal"}) do %>
```

But it still goes to the index action in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url for the [`form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) is being supplied by the `recipes_path` parameter, so depending on how you've set up the route, you'll need to change that.

For instance, if you set up the route like:

```
resources :recipes do
  get :filter, on: :collection
end
```

you should have a `filter_recipes_path` you can use instead of `recipes_path`. Otherwise, you can use the `as:` option to create a named helper. Lastly, if you don't want a named helper for that route, you can just use: `url_for`. So one of the following should work:

```
form_tag(filter_recipes_path, method: 'get', ...) do
```

or

```
form_tag(url_for(controller: :recipes, action: :filter), method: 'get' ...) do
```

Comment: the get :filter, on: :collection was what I was looking for.  Everything else I tried added it to the url /recipes/:recipe_id/filter, which isnt what I was trying to do.  Thanks